# How to get stackTrace from caller

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to be able to display in the log who caused the error:

```
def printError(errorMessage: String): Error = {
   new Error(errorMessage, /* create stack trace */)
}

def badMethod(...): IO[Error, ...] = {
    ...
    IO.fail(printError("This is bad"))
}
```

I want something inside `printError` which would show that the error was created in `badMethod`.

I tried with `Thread.getAllStackTraces.get(Thread.currentThread()).toList` but I get the head of the stack in `printError`.

In unit testing, there is the `Position` class which could do that but I don't know how to use it in none-test context.

Maybe some `implicit` something would do it ?

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a really good solution to this problem. I think you have to choose one of the following options each with its own drawbacks:

1. Live with the head of the stack being `printError`. I'm not sure if this is really that bad an option. By the way there is a simpler [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) call that you can use as in `Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()`
2. Add an explicit argument `printError`
3. Try to hack around returned `StackTraceElement[]` to remove some top element(s) that you don't want to be seen. Beware that this might be not that easy because potentially compiler might inline some method calls.
4. Create a custom macros-based solution like ScalaTest's [Position](http://doc.scalactic.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalactic.source.Position). I don't think you can do it without using a macro though. On the other hand the macro should not be complicated because macros `Context` has an [`enclosingPosition`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/macros/blackbox/Context.html#enclosingPosition:Enclosures.this.Position) property. But beware that macros are one of the least stable parts of the Scala so it might be not very future-proof.
5. Directly use ScalaTest's [`Position`](http://doc.scalactic.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalactic.source.Position) which was moved to an independent project [Scalactic](http://www.scalactic.org/) that you can use in your production code. This is similar to #4 but you move the burden of maintenance of your solution to the guys behind ScalaTest.

The drawback of #4 and #5 is that you get only source line position of the `badMethod` instead of the whole stack trace which is IMHO much worse for the debugging of the problems.

6. Combine #3 and #4 to create a macro that will create a wrapper value over `Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()` instead of `Context.enclosingPosition` and pass it as your "position".

---

## Update on #6

Actually implementing #6 is not that hard if you already have macros in your project and you can use [quasiquotes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html). Here is a simple PoC:

**Macro project**

```
package so.stacktrace
import scala.language.experimental.macros

class StackTraceWrapper(t: Throwable) {
  lazy val stackTrace: List[String] = t.getStackTrace().toList.map(_.toString)
}

object StackTraceWrapper {
  implicit def currentStackTrace: StackTraceWrapper = macro StackTraceWrapperMacro.buildCurrent
}


object StackTraceWrapperMacro {

  import scala.reflect.macros.Context

  def buildCurrent(context: Context) = {
    import context.universe._
    // note that package here should match the actual package!
    q"new so.stacktrace.StackTraceWrapper(new Throwable())"
  }
}
```

**Main project**

```
object StackTraceUsage extends App {

  import so.stacktrace.StackTraceWrapper

  case class Error(msg: String, stackTrace: List[String])

  object Error {
    def apply(msg: String)(implicit stw: StackTraceWrapper): Error = new Error(msg, stw.stackTrace)
  }


  def badMethod(): Unit = {
    println(Error("Test error"))
  }

  def badMethodCaller():Unit = {
    badMethod()
  }

  badMethodCaller()
}
```

This works for me as I would expect

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @Wonay, take a look at my update with a simple PoC for #6

Comment: Ok, but macros at this point guys? They’re hard to recommend, unless you’re content to stick with Scala 2.x forever and avoid major refactoring in the future. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Lasf, partially I agree and I actually put this is a drawback in my item #4. But given how simple the macro is and the fact that Scala is not going to get rid of all macros altogether just change flavors, I think this might be a reasonable trade-off.

Comment: @SergGr fair enough. Happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Throwable` in the caller, wherever you want the stack trace to begin,

```
def badMethod(...): IO[Error, ...] = {
    ...
    val t = new Throwable
    IO.fail(printError("This is bad", t))
}
```

and then pass that to your `printError` method:

```
def printError(errorMessage: String, t: Throwable): Error = {
   new Error(errorMessage, t.getStackTrace.toList.map(_.toString))
}
```

I don't know what the second parameter in your `Error` class wants but I assume from your question that it wants a `List[String]`. If it were a `String` instead you could call `t.getStackTraceString`.

That said, were you to just use `Throwable` instead of the `Error` class, this would all be done for you... but I assume you have your reasons.

Comment: I figured I could do that but I was trying not to add more constraint on the caller :/

Comment: @Wonay Would be helpful to add 1) that you figured you could do it like this and 2) that you want to avoid changing your `badMethod` at all to your question